# flutter adding geolocator to project giving errors

Tags: plugins, flutter, geolocation

I'm trying to use geolocator to get users location. However after installing dependencies and running it. I get a ton of errors. When I remove it and rerun, all errors are gone. I've tried multiple versions of the plugin and still same error. Here's my log output:

```
WARNING: This version of firebase_core will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See "url" for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:905: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:905: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.

  Command: C:\Users\Mike\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\4564870280758e11a31e0f822b4b55cc\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.hikelocator.hikelocator\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\Mike\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.1.aar\ff2bf124a1c2911ea68cc7f1f5d69383\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

  C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

  C:\Users\Mike\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.1.aar\b0d75b3838389273bb7c4663ccc599be\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  C:\Users\Mike\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.1.aar\b0d75b3838389273bb7c4663ccc599be\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\Mike\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\4564870280758e11a31e0f822b4b55cc\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.hikelocator.hikelocator\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\Mike\Documents\HikeLocator\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I even commented out the firebase_core one thinking it might be conflicting with geolocator, but I'm still getting the same error. Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.0.3+3
  geolocator: ^3.0.0
  http: ^0.12.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.5.8
  #firebase_core: ^0.3.0+2
  firebase_database: ^2.0.1+1
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the geolocator 2.1.1 ? The AndroidX compatible versions cause problems sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's that some of the libraries you depend on supports AndroidX while the others don't. For AndroidX -less solution

Try replacing:

```
geolocator: ^3.0.0
```

with:

```
geolocator: ^2.1.1
permission_handler: "2.1.2"
google_api_availability: "1.0.4"
```

More info [here](https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-geolocator/issues/196), [here](https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-geolocator/issues/194) and [here](https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-geolocator/issues/185).

Comment: sweet that worked. I tried 2.1.1, but not with the other 2 lines. thank you so much