# Build issue after adding flutter_email_sender 2.0.0 library to Flutter App in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I can no longer get my Android App to build after adding this library to my pubspec.yaml file.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_email_sender#-installing-tab-

I'm getting the following error:

```
/Users/duffette/AndroidStudioProjects/undaunted_golf_flutter/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 Error:
    Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-38:19 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-38:19 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at (help link)

BUILD FAILED in 8s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.


 See (link) for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
*******************************************************************************************
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I've already migrated my project to AndroidX.
I've made sure that compileSdkVersion 28 and targetSdkVersion 28.

I have successfully added other libraries added to my project.

I'm attempting to follow the instructions to add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to `<application>` element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-38:19 to override., but I haven't been successful.

Comment: Import the version which does not have the AndroidX compatibility. Try using version 1.2.0

Comment: Thanks @AdityaNigam. I tried that, but got the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900809/8240072 try this.